# Providing a partial view in an ASP.net MVC4 code library?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, deployment

I've been writing a code library for ASP.net MVC4 I'm called "ExpressForms".  The idea is to automate common coding tasks associated with displaying tabular data.

Recently, I started writing code that will automatically display a "filter" widget for each column in the grid so that the user can type to find certain records.  The filter automatically adapts to the data type associated with each column and adds a rich set of features, such as autocomplete, and page state bookmarking.

To implement these features, I've created some partial views that the associated classes use to output HTML to render these widgets.

The issue I have is that once someone downloads the library, they must manually copy the partial views to their ASP.net MVC4 project!  Is there a way to configure my library (which is a .net class library project) so that a developer who downloads my library doesn't have to manually copy the partial views into his web project?

Comment: Have you looked into creating a nuget package?  I think with nuget on install you could plop your partials in the Views/Shared folder or something similar.

Comment: I'm not familiar with creating nuget packages.  Sounds like I should look in to it.  That would probably help with associated .js files, as well.